# How to change listing per page option?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-list

I am trying to **change per page option in magento 2 on product listing page**

- Currently its `9, 15, 30` by default in **toolbar**
- I want to change it to `12, 24, 48, 96` etc

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In magento 2 its changes from less file(css). admin option  is not available.

Comment: could you guide me , where I can find this in admin , I am looking from half an hour and couldn't find it

Comment: @Yogesh , how can I achieve this please help

Comment: Please refer this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117311/magento-2-change-number-of-items-per-row

Comment: you took the quest in wrong way @yogesh , in above link it about product per row not per page .. I already seen that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to admin `Store > Configuration > Catalog > Storefront`

Now there are two things

- Products per Page on Grid **Allowed Values**

  Enter your desired no here with comma like `12,24,48,96`
- Products per Page on **Grid Default Value**

  Value you enter here must be defined in Allowed Values.

  like you can enter from these values only `12,24,48,96.`

**See how it looks after changing**

[image]

Clear your cache and it should work smoothly

Comment: is it must to show 12 products in default grid value or I can use 9 instead ?

Comment: yes, value should from allowed values only

Comment: NOTE: not all themes support this behavior (like some custom ones), although a majority of the commercial themes do.

Comment: @ManojDeswal, i want to set for specific category like 12 products in a grid so what should i do for that ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal, let me send you code for that.

Answer (score 2):

you can change in admin
Store >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Catalog >> Frontend TAB

Answer (score 2):

You can change it via admin panel in section **Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog**.

You are interested in the fields **Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values** and **Products per Page on List Allowed Values**.

Answer (score 2):

For grid view:

- Go to **Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront**.
- Change value of **Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values**.
- Save Configuration and flush cache.

Please check the screenshot for reference.

[image: Store Front Section]

In a similar way, you can change for list view also.

**Note:** You also need to make sure that the value of **Products per Page on Grid Default Value** should contain a value from the values of **Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values** only.

**Note:** Flush Magento Cache before checking the frontend.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: i set 12,24,36, but still its loading all products on list page

Answer (score 2):

You can change it from `Admin >> STORES >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Storefront >>  Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change 9, 15, 30 by default in the toolbar on the product listing page.

Go To Your Magento admin Panel : in **Store**->**Configuration**->**Catalog**->**Catalog**->**Store Front**

Here You Can Find Two Settings,

**Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values**

**Products per Page on List Allowed Values**

Where U Can Change Limits Accordingly By Giving Appropriate Values Separated By **,(Comma)**.