# Number of pages on category page

Tags: magento2.3, porto-theme

I'm using magento 2.3.1 with porto theme.

I would like to change the number of pages which are display in category page. I need all the pages be visible and no the near 4 of current page

[image]

Is anybody knows how can change this?

Comment: you want to remove the pagination?

Comment: You help me, i try to find class="pages" in code, i didn;t notice that is pagination which can be edited from backend. Thank you!

Comment: You are always welcome Happy to help! ;)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/n9255z   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198186/how-to-change-listing-per-page-option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change listing per page option?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198186/how-to-change-listing-per-page-option)

Answer (score 0):

From your question I found that you want to edit the pagination. To change the pagination 
 or the number of pages to be shown on the front-end on the category & search page you can follow the below guidelines.

- Go to Admin > CONTENT > Design > Configuration.
- Click on the edit link in a particular **Store view** or **Website**.
- Click on the **Pagination** tab.
- Update the **Pagination Frame** with the number of pages you want to show to be given as an option in the back-end.
- Save the configuration by clicking on the **Save Configuration** button & flush the cache.