# How to change number of items in a row Magento 2

Tags: magento2, less, items

I've been through topics like this:
[Magento 2 change number of items per row](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117311/magento-2-change-number-of-items-per-row)

All of them claims, that if I wanna change my items row to display 4 instead of 5, then I would have to change in a file called `_listings.less`

Seems simple enough, but my issue appeared, when I discovered, that I am missing this file.

Actually my folder structure looks way different. I did a search all over my `FTP` to find the file, but it didn't find it.

I am missing the `web-folder` in `/public_html/app/design/frontend/Outline/outline6/Magento_Catalog`

I've been looking around, but it seems that I need to find this file to do it officially, and not in an unrecommended way.

How can I move on from here?

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that on the backend.
You just need to navigate on the Category Page and update the Product per row!

Just go on `Catalog -> Categories -> Select Categories you want -> Display Settings -> Product per row`

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is no such option for me. This is my options: https://ibb.co/St1Pdx8